# Turn off / ignore message box's in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way of turning off or ignoring message boxes which have been programmed into a user form?

I have tried `Application.Displayalerts=False` however, this only seems to apply to excel error messages.

Comment: How do these `MsgBox's` appear - can you provide the code, or better a sample workbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the messagebox is programmed to display, it will display.  However, you could do something like this:

```
Dim displayMesssageBoxes = [insert 0 if you do not want messageboxes displayed;1 if you do]
if displayMessageBoxes == 1
    [insert code to display mesagebox here]
else
end
```